# Is it possible to change jQRangeSlider size after constructor initialized?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the jQRangeSlider library. I do not see any documentation about this. I am trying to change the size of the slider after the constructor has already been run.

```
<div id="dateSlider"></div>
<script>
    $("#dateSlider").dateRangeSlider({
    bounds:{
                min: new Date("$oldest"),
                max: new Date("$newest")
  },
  defaultValues:{
                min: new Date(2002,01,17),
                max: new Date(2007,01,17)
              }});


</script>
```

Specifically what I am trying to do is:

- User selects date with slider
- User hits submit button and form gets submitted
- Returned results get filtered by selected date range AND
- Date range is still selected on the jQRangeSlider <-- Because of the way my project is setup, I will need to do it after jQRangeSlider constructor has run.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you looked everywhere? :)
http://ghusse.github.io/jQRangeSlider/methods.html#resizeMethod